# NodeJS : Send SMS via GSM device connected at serial port

Tags: node.js, sms

I need to send SMS via a GSM device connected to the PC at serial COM1 port.

I am able to receive SMS but when I try to send an SMS, it's never delivered. When I try connecting the GSM device via hyper terminals and give the command to send SMS it works fine. Below is my code:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", {
    baudrate: 9600,  dataBits: 8,  parity: 'none',  stopBits: 1, flowControl: false, xon : false, rtscts:false, xoff:false, xany:false, buffersize:0
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log('Serial communication open');
    serialPort.write("AT+CMGF=1");
    serialPort.write('\r');
    delay(10);
    serialPort.write("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
    serialPort.write('\r');
    delay(10);
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        gsm_message_sending(serialPort, "S", "1111111111"); //valid number only
    });
});

function gsm_message_sending(serial,message,phone_no)
{
    serial.write("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(100); // a simple for loop
    serial.write("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); 
    serial.write('\r');
    delay(200);
    serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"+91");
    serial.write(phone_no);
    serial.write('"')
    serial.write('\r');
    serial.write(message); 
    //Now I have to send two time consecutively Ctrl+Z or char - 26
    //I am assuming that maybe cause of below code SMS are not being send
    // Method 1 :
    // serial.write(String.fromCharCode(26)) 
    //serial.write(String.fromCharCode(26)) 
    //Method 2
    //serial.write(Buffer([0x1A]));
    //serial.write(Buffer([0x1A]));
    //serial.write('^z');
    //serial.write('^z');
}
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing or why the SMS is not going out?

Comment: Try removing your blocking delays, creating a queue of commands (lines) to send, and set up a 100ms timeout (or whatever length you want) which reads from this queue and sends.  I don't know what you're using for this synchronous delay, but it may be blocking your serial port library.  Also, install a virtual serial port utility so you can capture the traffic between your application and your hardware, to make debugging easier.

Comment: I commented out all delays and the delay is a simple for loop counter of its args as passed. Unfortunately it still does not works out. I feel I am unable to send CTRL + Z to serial port - maybe that is the issue

Comment: Your `Buffer([0x1a])` method is correct.  Again, without being able to see what's happening over the wire, it's hard to debug.  Use a virtual serial port driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
     baudrate: 9600,  dataBits: 8,  parity: 'none',  stopBits: 1, flowControl: false, xon : false, rtscts:false, xoff:false, xany:false, buffersize:0
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log('Serial communication open');
    serialPort.write("AT^SYSCFG=13,1,3FFFFFFF,2,4");
    serialPort.write('\r');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Received data: " + data);
    });
    gsm_message_sending(serialPort, "test2", "<you phone number>");
});

function gsm_message_sending(serial, message, phone_no) {
    serial.write("AT+CMGF=1");
    serial.write('\r');
    serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"");
    serial.write(phone_no);
    serial.write('"')
    serial.write('\r');
    serial.write(message); 
    serial.write(Buffer([0x1A]));
    serial.write('^z');
}
```

works perfectly for me with E3131 modem.
As you can see, I changed a bit the script so that it only emits one sms and prints the messages:

```
Received data: AT^SYSCFG=13,1,3FFFFFFF,2,4
Received data:
OK

Received data: AT+CMGF=1
Received data:
OK

Received data: AT+CMGS="
Received data: 0671358943
Received data: "
Received data:
>
Received data: test2
Received data:
Received data: ^z
Received data:
+CMGS: 28

OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo nodejs yourfilejs.js
```

on ubuntu if without sudo will raise error 'Permission denied'

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Mermoz's answer. But it gave me a Buffer deprecated warning and couldn't send a message. Here is the solution worked for me. Hope that would help someone.

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
function sendSMS(){
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
    baudRate: 9600,  dataBits: 8,  parity: 'none',  stopBits: 1, flowControl: false, xon : false, rtscts:false, xoff:false, xany:false, buffersize:0
});

serialPort.on("open", async function () {
    console.log('Serial communication open');
    serialPort.write("AT+CMGF=1\r",11);
    await sleep(100);
    serialPort.write("AT+CSCS=\"gsm\"\r",15);
    await sleep(100);
    serialPort.write("AT+CSCA=\"<Service center number>\"\r",19);
    await sleep(100);
    serialPort.write("AT+CMGS=\"<Receiver's number>\"\r\n\0",23);
    await sleep(1000);
    serialPort.write("test\r",6);
    await sleep(1000);
    serialPort.write("\r",0);
    await sleep(100);
    serialPort.write("\x1A",2);
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Received data: " + data);
    });
});
}
function sleep(ms){
return new Promise(resolve=>{
    setTimeout(resolve,ms)
})
}
```

Comment: `serialPort.write("AT+CSCS=\"IRA\"\r",15);` is required for modern modems which use ACM