# Sending an SMS using a 3G dongle in node.js

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, com, sms

Uhh... so I'm kind of confused with something, let me explain what I'm trying to do...
So, I have a C# App, Okay wait don't go and say invalid keyword yet!

okay so I have a C# app that can send data like text to my node.js app using HTTP Clients, now I'm trying to use my 3G Dongle to send SMS on requests, this thing even has something to do with Serial-Ports,

C# --> Sends Request --> Message and phone number logged in console --> Sends SMS -->  `res.send('200');` :)

Now I got everything covered except the SMS Integration, Now to do that I need to find the COM where the DONGLE is located, not sure about this and I'm on a raspberry pi 4

Here are a few images of my dongle
[image: Back part of my Dongle]
[image: Front part of my Dongle]

Now I connected this to my Pi and then read some docs and then tried finding the com by using this command `dmesg | grep tty` when I did this, this is what I saw...

[image: terminal]

Here's my JS code,

```js
app.post("/sms", (req, res) => {
    var results = req.body;
    var a = results.split(':')
    console.log('Message - ' + a[0] + "  Phone number - " + a[1]);
});
```

So as you can see I'm stuck everywhere and need help, I saw a youtube video and got some code for the SMS sending

Video --> https://youtu.be/u0m-GYSKQ7g
Another relevant post --> [NodeJS : Send SMS via GSM device connected at serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172197/nodejs-send-sms-via-gsm-device-connected-at-serial-port/29555549)

Can someone help me understand this stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand your question, but did you at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172197/nodejs-send-sms-via-gsm-device-connected-at-serial-port?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?

Comment: Hey so I'm at stage one I need to find out the following 1) Which COM is the dongle located in 2) Sending SMS with node.js 3) Implementing it in the main code

Comment: I still don't get it. When you use the serial port you don't use HTTP but AT commands (that you can send using javascript, of course with a serial module). For the COM port , I had a similar issue (on linux and with Elixir) and found no other solution than sending a ATZ (or any other commenad) on all ports with a timeout and if you get OK, you have your port